# How does it work linear interpolation? It fails to predict the right value between points

Tags: python, arrays, list, linear-interpolation

My code does not work when I apply a linear interpolation between points.

Code

```
y= [0.1 ,0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.71]

x= [44.72, 43.4, 41.5, 39.9, 37.73, 36.1, 33.6, 31.5, 29.7, 26.4, 21.6, 16.8, 3.6, 0] 

x_new = 25

y_new = np.interp(x_new, x, y)
print(y_new)
plt.plot(x, y, "og-", x_new, y_new, "or");
```

Result

[image: The red dot should be on the green line.]

Expected result
[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: From the documentation for `numpy.interp()`: "One-dimensional linear interpolation for _monotonically increasing_ sample points."  You need to reorder your arrays so that the X values are in increasing order.

Comment: Reverse both lists so that the X values are ascending rather than descending.

Comment: Have you considered scipy.interpolate.interp1d instead?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) say that the x values must be monotonically increasing. Yours don't.

> The x-coordinate sequence is expected to be increasing, but this is
> not explicitly enforced. However, if the sequence xp is
> non-increasing, interpolation results are meaningless.
>
> Note that, since NaN is unsortable, xp also cannot contain NaNs.
>
> A simple check for xp being strictly increasing is:
>
> `np.all(np.diff(xp) > 0)`

Comment: Ok, I see now. Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: @chrisis `x[::-1]` seems to be monotonically increasing if I eyeballed it correctly.

Comment: Unfortunatly, it still does not work this method. 4